# React js webpack redux app - convert to static site - boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, react-redux, react-boilerplate

I have a strange problem with this tool
https://github.com/kriasoft/react-static-boilerplate

I have an React-redux-wepback app and want to build as a static site

after clone react-static-boilerplate project from github and install all dependencies
and use $ yarn start, everything working fine except one thing,
When I click on "About" button it's not redirecting me to /about
it just change address and stay in home page,

When I use $ yarn build, and copy all files from public folder to my hosting it's working just perfect

but I want to test it in development mode (yarn start) on my vps
and there is weird stuff

fragment of my routes.json

```
 {
    "path": "/about",
    "page": "./about"    
  },
```

but if I change my routes json to

```
 {
    "path": "/sign_up",
    "page": "./sign_up",
    "chunk": "main"
  },
```

/about working in development mode (yarn start) but not working after yarn build and copy to static files to hosting

I don't understand that chunk option, any help please?

Or maybe there is more easy way than boilerplate tool to convert React app to a static app which would be working on basic hosting (no VPS etc)?

Comment: Chunks are used to split your code. Hard to give an answer without the rest of the file. Check the docs here: https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#chunk-content

If you are using Amazon S3, check the issue `#1080` on the project repo for a possible solution.

Side note: For future projects have a look at `create-react-app` from FB. It creates a simple react boilerplate that has a very good toolset. Their `build` command works like a charm for generating static sites.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout https://phenomic.io/

It's a React to static HTML generator.